# How can I fix this image size in Xcode Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzjJN.jpg

I draw it in Xcode, but the simulator inside of picture is getting bigger. Does anyone know how to fix it??

[image]

Comment: Left picture is Xcode, Right side pic is Simulator.. and it is a button image.

Comment: Please add more details. What you are asking for?

Comment: It seems that you have given only position constraints to subviews. However, you have to constraint them with size constraints such as width and height as well.

Comment: I made button and add image.. and I test it in Simulator but the button image is getting bigger. What should I do? I don't want that button img bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try the highlighted constraints with red mark shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to [set Height & Width constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQQ6m.png).

Be aware, by default, it will deform the aspect ratio of the image if you'r given constraints doesn't match the original image ratio.

To be safe, I personally prefer setting Content-Mode to [Aspect Fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcXZA.png)/[Aspect Fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWep4.png) for added control over the aspect ratio of the image.

Remember to mark `Clip-to-Bounds` if you select `Aspect Fill`, as the the side of the image outside of the `image-frame` won't be automatically cut if you don't do so.

There's screenshots in the hyperlink, I hope they help.